# How to avoid asp:UpdatePanel duplicate my contents?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm creating a webpage that refreshes every 5 seconds to show how much order is left. The problem is after it's refreshed, my contents starts to duplicate.
Here, the brief of my problems :
I'm showing : 
`Order Offline : 1 / Order Online : 0.`
After Refresh, it will be :
`Order Offline : 11 / Order Online : 00.`
I refresh the page with with `asp:UpdatePanel` `Triggers` and `asp:Timer` event

I've tried googling for the answer and mostly I found answers by setting the `ViewState` to `Disabled` and also I've tried to change `UpdateMode` to `Conditional`

Here is my code's snippets :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000"></asp:Timer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="image.png" Width="170" ID="ClsBtn" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right;">
                <span id="date" style="font-size:10px; font-weight: 900;"></span>
                <span id="time" style="font-size:10px; font-weight: 900;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right;">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTQ" runat="server">
                    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" /></Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <span style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900;">OFFLINE : <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTotalQueue" /> / ONLINE : <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTotalQueueM" /></span>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

and this is my code behind :

```vb
phTotalQueue.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("" & dtTO.Rows(0).Item("TotalOrderOffline") & ""))
```

```vb
phTotalQueueM.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("" & dtTO2.Rows(0).Item("TotalOrderOnline") & ""))
```

I expect the output to be `Order Offline : 1 / Order Online : 0.` with no duplicate contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first understand what happens: Your page is generated on the server, sent out to the browser, where it is displayed and then, each time it is being refreshed the server is requested and at that time, a `LiteralControl` is added to `phTotalQueue` and `phTotalQueueM`, respectively. Each time this runs, the controls already existent in `phTotalQueue` and `phTotalQueueM`, respectively will remain there, displaying the older values, but a new such control is being generated, displaying the new value besides the older values. I would like to kindly advise you to make sure you have an identifiable `LiteralControl` in your `UpdatePanel`s, having an `ID`:

```
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTQ" runat="server">
                    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" /></Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <span style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900;">OFFLINE : <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTotalQueue"><asp:Literal ID="phTotalQueueText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:PlaceHolder> / ONLINE : <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTotalQueueM"><asp:Literal ID="phTotalQueueMText" runat="server"></asp:Literal></asp:PlaceHolder></span>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now, since you have identifiable `LiteralControl` instances, let's change the code-behind:

```
phTotalQueueText.Text = "" & dtTO.Rows(0).Item("TotalOrderOffline") & ""
```

and

```
phTotalQueueMText.Text = "" & dtTO2.Rows(0).Item("TotalOrderOnline") & ""
```

Alternatively you can remove the old controls from your `UpdatePanel`s, or find them and modify their `Text` attribute, but those are hacky ways and I recommend the usage of identifiable tags.

Comment: I've tried it, it works like a charm !! 
You've save my life and also my time. 
Thank you so much @Lajos Arpad.
Also I have changed the ID of `asp:PlaceHolder` and Voila !! IT WORKS :) :)